# Call VBA function in another workbook from spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, reference

Here's the function definition:

```
Public Function StockQuote(strSymbol As String) As Double
```

It's stored in a module in an already-loaded worksheet ("My Macros.xlsm", in my Startup folder).

I want to call it from another workbook, as a cell reference:

Workbook1.xlsm cell A1:

```
=StockQuote("AAPL")
```

But all i get are NAME errors.

Comment: I think you need to qualify it, like `=[My Macros.xlsm]StockQuote("AAPL")` or something like that. Play around with that for a minute. (I'm currently on a PC without MS Office or I would try to confirm the correcty formula structure)

Comment: This question has been [asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012463/how-to-call-function-from-another-specific-workbook-in-vba)

Comment: Incorrect, Brian Camire. The question and answer you linked to refer to calls made from VBA; I am trying to make the call from the spreadsheet itself.

That question has nothing to do with this one, because the two interfaces use completely different languages.

Comment: Asside from what @BrianCamire commented, you can also [check this out](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2010/05/26/excel-udf-tutorial/)

Comment: Once you add the reference, the VBA function can be called like a worksheet function.

Comment: Thank you. THAT finally worked.

First I had to rename the project, though - Excel names the VBA project in every file exactly the same, which produced a name conflict, which meant it wouldn't load the functions.

Pain in the ass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

=My Macros.xlsm!StockQuote("AAPL")

='C:\SomeFolder\My Macros.xlsm'!StockQuote("AAPL")

Work either.

But in order to work you shoud open the My Macros.xlsm workbook after Workbook1.xlsm, from the excel window of Workbook1.xlsm

Comment: Works, and it doesn't seem to matter which workbook is opened first.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving your XLSM workbook containing the function as an XLAM instead: when the XLAM is open other workbooks should be able to see your UDF.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.

It should run when the worksheet is activated and put the return value of your function in cell A1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Range("A1") = StockQuote("AAPL")
End Sub
```

You may need to structure it differently if the current worksheet can't see your function

Comment: Sure, but that's very different. I can't update it without heading into the VBA editor, for instance (or creating some sort of update trigger). And I can't casually add this function in cells - I'd have to code the cell locations in every time.