# How To Call a Subroutine From Another Object

Tags: vba, object, vb6

I am not entirely sure if this is possible, but assuming with us being able to set object references I don't see why not.

To start off, the object that contains the subroutine in question is Excel itself. I am wanting to call one of Excel's VBA subroutines using a different program's VB6 script editor.

I have tried the following without success, but hopefully you can see what I am trying to accomplish here:

```
Sub Excel_Test()
    Dim appXL As Object
    Set appXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    Call appXL.Project1.Module1.Test()
End Sub
```

Obviously this code is not working - but what would be the proper Syntax (if one exists) to call the Macro `Test`, located in `Module1` contained in Excel's object?

Comment: Note sure what you mean by "the object that contains the subroutine in question is Excel itself".  Are you referring to a method in the Excel Object Model, or in a workbook somewhere (like your `Call` statement would suggest)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call an Excel macro from a different Workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741828/call-an-excel-macro-from-a-different-workbook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate other instances of excel if you identify them by some criteria like the workbook name,

try like

**Code:**

```
set otherinstance = getobject(,"fullpath\filename.xls")
otherinstance.application.run "macroname"
```