# How to Call a Module stored on a Cloud Drive

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel 2016 VBA program which contains a Module 1 which uses a Dll file.  I would like to store the Module 1 and Dll file on a secure server and Call back to the main program as required. I think one way this maybe done is store Module 1 on the server and rename Module 1 and Module 2 in the program as use Module 2 to Call Module 1.  Is this possible??

Comment: ["Call an Excel macro from a different Workbook"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741828/call-an-excel-macro-from-a-different-workbook)

Comment: If, when you say it's "on a cloud drive", that you mean it's in like a local folder on your pc that will sync with the cloud service then the question I shared should work. If that's not the case then I'm thinking we need more clarification about this cloud drive

Comment: What do you mean by "on a secure server"? Secure from what? What is the purpose of doing that?

Comment: I am talking about a company server that is secured from hacking.  We what to store the VBA module and Dll files there and when a user wishes to use the excel program, they can only enter data and view and print the results.  We want to install a coded Module 2 that calls the Module1 and uses the Dll on the server.  I hope this provides more information

Comment: I guess no one out there knows how to solve my question, or my question needs more clarification.  I will try more clarification - I have and excel VBA program on my desk top which has a module with code.  I need to program this module to Call the code of a different module which is stored on a file server.  Can this be done please.