# Calling a macro saved in a different workbook without linking

Tags: excel, vba

I created some code to open a workbook and run a macro saved in that workbook but I'm getting an error 'expected sub/function'. The code is below. Your help is  greatly appreciated!

```
Sub practice()
Const folderPath As String = "I:\Ben\New Stores\Reports"
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Dim MyFolder As Object
Set MyFolder = fso.GetFolder(folderPath)

Application.Run "'6wk File to Run.xlsm'!button2_click"

End Sub
```

EDIT The working code is above

Comment: Try using this line 'Application.Run ("'6wk File to Run.xlsm'!Macroname")'

Comment: make sure macro is scoped to all openworkbooks and it may need to be Public Sub...

Comment: How do I change scope to all openworkbooks and make it a public sub? It's saying the macro may not be available in this workbook or is disabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call function from another specific workbook in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012463/how-to-call-function-from-another-specific-workbook-in-vba)

Comment: I got it to work once I added the other workbook as a reference. BUT it won't let me close the referenced workbook after the macro is run. I need to be able to close it and open a different application. Any ideas??

Comment: That is most likely because you need the elements I specified and also you may need the sheetname after the ! and before the macro name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like (change worksheet name as appropriate and make sure macro is scoped to all openworkbooks). You may or may not need the sheet between the workbook name and the button2.

```
Application.Run ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!Sheet1.Button2_click"
```

Where Button2 is Public Scope

[image: Scoping in all open workbooks]

To make Button2 public simply make sure it is

```
Public Sub Button2_Click
```

Comment: QHarr thanks for the help! I'm still having trouble with this though. I have removed the link to the document because I need to be able to close the file (plus it wasn't working with the link anyway). I have added the sheet name but am still getting error cannot run the macro. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the scope? And that macros are enabled?

Comment: I changed Sub Button2_Click to Public Sub Button2_Click. Is that what you mean? Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: The macros in part: see bottom of image. Tbh shouldn’t need all this but worth trying.

Comment: Interesting... Ok yes they all look like the image you sent.

Comment: What version excel you running? And OS?

Comment: Pretty sure I'm running the latest verson of excel on a PC

Comment: Figured out that if the document name has spaces in it you must surround the filename with apostrophes. (see above) Thanks for your help QHarr! Wouldn't have been able to figure it out without you and everyone else who helped.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
Application.Run (ActiveWorkbook.name & "!button2_click")
```