# Normal.dot and Personal.xlsb

Tags: excel, vba

For using *Word* I have many public subs and functions stored in Normal.dot. I can use all of them in any module I write in any other Word project. For instance this elementary function stored in Normal.dot,

```
Public Function BooleanString(b As Boolean) As String
    If b Then BooleanString = "Yes!" Else BooleanString = "No!"
End Function
```

can be used from other projects as

```
Sub TestNormal()
    Debug.Print BooleanString(True)
End Sub
```

Using *Excel* I cannot duplicate this behavior: Public subs and functions I have stored in Personal.xlsb (among then the one above) seem not to be visible when called from a module in the VBAProject belonging to any other spreadsheet than Personal.xlsb, resulting in “Sub or Function not defined”.

I have made sure that the Excel option box “Have trust in the VBA project model” (translated from the Danish version) is checked. Also, using “View”, I have made sure that Personal.xlsb is not hidden; it shows up every time I open Excel.

What am I doing wrong or missing here?

Best regards
Holger Nielsen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call function from another specific workbook in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012463/how-to-call-function-from-another-specific-workbook-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, using Functions/Subs of Personal.xlsb is a little different...

In order to use a UDF function, let us say, `testMultiplication`:

```
    Function testMultiplication(x As Long, y As Long) As Long
         testMultiplication = x * y
    End Function
```

it can be called from the (other) workbook sheet cell in this way:

```
    =Personal.xlsb!testMultiplication(3, 4)
```

In order to call Personal.xlsb `Subs` and `Functions`, a reference to the hidden workbook `VBAProject` is necessary...

To do that, follow the next steps, please:

1. Firstly give to the Personal.xlsb VBAProject an elocvent name (also to avoid name conflict error, keeping it like VBAProject):

   a) In VBE - Project Explorer, right click on its `VBAProject`, choose `VBAProject Properties...` and change the standard name in, let us say, 'PersVBAProject`.

   b) Then click on a module of the workbook you want to add the reference and use Tools -> References. Find 'PersVBAProject`, check it and press` OK`.
2. Starting from that moment the subs/functions of Prsonal.xlsb can be directly called from the specific workbook
3. In order to programmatically add the reference, use the next code, please:

```
    Sub AddPersonalXLSBRef()
      'It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility ...'
        Dim VBe As VBIDE.VBe, vbPr As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim objRef As VBIDE.Reference, boolFound As Boolean
    
        Set VBe = Application.VBe
        Set vbPr = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    
        'check if reference to Personal.xlsb exists:
        'Please, take care to have its VBAProject name modified in `PersVBProject`
        'or something else and, in such a case, adapt the following lines accordingly
        For Each objRef In vbPr.References
            If objRef.Name = "PersVBProject" Then
                MsgBox "Reference to Personal.xlsb already exists"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
         'add the reference, if not exist:
         vbPr.References.AddFromFile Application.StartupPath & "\Personal.xlsb"
    
         MsgBox "Reference to Personal.xlsb added Successfully"
    End Sub
```

It adds the reference to the active workbook project. The code can be adapted to add it to all open workbooks (not having it added, yet)...

Comment: Hello FaneDuru!
I followed your advice given above, and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much for taking time to provide a thorough answer.

Comment: @Holger Nielsen: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else, searching for a similar issue, will know that the answer was accepted and the code works... :)